# Updating document library column when document in checked out

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, event-receivers, check-out

I am working on one small project on SharePoint online(E3), requirement is as per below.

Whenever any user check out the document,  the document library column "isApproved" should be set to "No"

one possible way is to use **remote event receivers in SharePoint**.

Is there any other workaround to achieve this, as I **at present we don't have development environment setup to create the event receivers for online.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try to achieve that with Flow, although not sure atm if the edited trigger starts flow on check out or only at check in.

Have a look at those
[Trigger Flow when document in SharePoint has been checked-in](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255181/trigger-flow-when-document-in-sharepoint-has-been-checked-in)

https://spblog.net/post/2019/05/29/microsoft-flow-guides-how-to-run-a-flow-when-a-document-is-published

Answer (score 0):

You can create SharePoint 2010 platform workflow to achieve your requirement.

In SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow, it contains the SharePoint 2010 workflow platform, you can use "Wait for Change in Document Check-Out Status" action in SharePoint 2010 workflow platform, and change the status to Check-out.

[image]

In addition, check start workflow automatically when an item is created/changed.

[image]